# RSA with EVP API

Tags: openssl, rsa

I'm looking to built custom engine and implement RSA algorithm with EVP API. 
Can anyone please guide me which structure I should implement and bind it to engine.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a custom `RSA_METHOD` using the `RSA_meth_*` functions documented here:

https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/RSA_meth_new.html

Then set it for use in your engine using `ENGINE_set_RSA`:

https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/ENGINE_set_RSA.html

There are some examples of this being done here:

https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/a9a8863b791a54625da2a079a496a31cb7f94482/engines/e_dasync.c#L193-L211

And here:

https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/a9a8863b791a54625da2a079a496a31cb7f94482/engines/e_capi.c#L425-L438
https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/a9a8863b791a54625da2a079a496a31cb7f94482/engines/e_capi.c#L546

Comment: thank you @MATT Caswell

Comment: how to call these RSA encrypt/decrypt function from tester side,so that respective function at engine side should get called ? can we wrap these function under EVP API ?

Comment: Yes. You can either set your RSA method to be the default method used by everything (including by EVP) using RSA_set_default_method(), or create your RSA objects using RSA_new_method() and pass your ENGINE as a parameter. With the latter method you then assign the RSA object you create to an EVP_PKEY via EVP_PKEY_assign_RSA().